# System cannot find my Tizen Studio Device Manager

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-studio

I downloaded and installed Tizen Studio with the Web Wearable package, through the package manager I also installed the Emulator Manager. When I try to launch the Device Manager(which I assume is installed since it's sitting in it's appropriately named folder) through the IDE I get the error: 'CreateProcess Error failed with error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.'

A problem I had before this one arose was another launch error telling me that the environment variable for JAVA_HOME wasn't set so I went ahead and created that variable and pointed it to the JDK I use and added JAVA_HOME in Path. This was after some searching about this issue and finding this solution.

After doing this the problem in the first paragraph emerged.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqLRw.jpg

I have browsed around and cannot seem to find this exact issue anywhere, would be very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Oracle JDK 8. That usually happens when you have incompatible JDK (or incompatible java versions). You may install Oracle JDK 8 at some optional path and direct to it with JAVA_HOME.

Comment: Apparently I was already using JDK 8 but I have botched the JAVA_HOME variable a bit. Thank you.